# Getting an error Markup of type 'html' not found

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.4

I am extending a class SomeDetailPage which extends SomePage which in turn extends WebPage. Now this SomeDetailPage is working fine and has no issues. But I have created a new class and extended some of its features and when I am trying to deploy it I am getting the error
org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupNotFoundException: Markup of type 'html' for component 'AboutUs' not found. Enable debug messages for org.apache.wicket.util.resource to get a list of all filenames tried: [Page class = AboutUs, id = 11, version = 0]. I have checked if the html is not copied into the folder which has AboutUs.class, but it's there, checked if naming was different, no use. I couldn't find why I am not able to run it and couldn't even find out the reason why so that I could atleast try a workaround. I am using Wicket 1.4.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if you've already done this, but you need to define the markup for your new class, and you also need to specify the markup hierarchy.
So if your new new class is called AboutUs.java, then AboutUs.html will contain -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wicket:extend xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd">

    <body ...>
    ...
    </body>
</wicket:extend>
```

You also need to modify the markup for SomeDetailPage to contain the following tag, at the point where your new markup should be inserted

```xml
<wicket:child/>
```

Comment: After reading your question again, I see that you did define the HTML, but I'll leave my answer there because I ran into this problem and it might be useful for others to see.

Comment: I haven't used <wicket:child/> earlier which was the issue, but I have figured that out and was thinking if nobody has answered I should answer and here you go, that's exactly the answer I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I've just come across the same error and it's great to find a solution in an answer published 9 yrs ago. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 4):

You should use wicket with [the maven archetype](http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html), it sets you up to solve exactly this problem.

Assuming you use maven (which you should), a source folder (like src/main/java) is not a resource folder (like src/main/resources). So if you need to copy resources from your source folder to the output, you need to add the source folder as a resource folder in your pom.xml:

```xml
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: +1, makes it clear that the whole src/main/java folder should be set as a resource and not ony your package folder (I had src/main/java/company/package instead, it didnt work)